# why is the NaN not being included in the count when i do a groupby? PYTHON "size" does NOT work as it doesn't give the count of NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want my function to count how many nans/nones appear in the column as well as whatever numbers or strings etc.

This differs from the using count vs size in the group by as the `size` doesn't give the number of occurrences of NaNs it just shows NaN at each row for those. Count does the same - open to changing how the function gets the count of occurrences as long as i am able to get desired output. Thanks in advance!!

This is the function:

```
def count_how_many(df: pd.DataFrame,in_col, out_col, inplace=False):
    def count_occurrences(dff: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
        return dff.groupby(in_col)[in_col].transform('count')
    if not inplace:
        copy_df = df.copy()
        copy_df[out_col] = count_occurrences(copy_df)
        return copy_df
    else:
        df[out_col] = count_occurrences(df)
        return None
```

My df1 looks like this:

| number |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| np.nan |
| np.nan |
| 4 |

And I want `count_how_many(df1, "number", "count")`    to look like this:

| number | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| np.nan | 2 |
| np.nan | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |

i need this function to work for strings as well
df2:

| item |
| --- |
| cookies |
| cake |
| brownie |
| cake |
| cake |
| brownie |

And I want `count_how_many(df2, "item", "count")`    to look like this:

| item | count |
| --- | --- |
| cookies | 1 |
| cake | 3 |
| brownie | 2 |
| cake | 3 |
| cake | 3 |
| brownie | 2 |

Comment: Use `size`, `count` ignores NaNs

Comment: @mozway when i use size it doesn't return a number for the Nans

Comment: No it gives you the total number of values. If you want to count the NaNs only use: `lambda x: x.isna().sum()`